# When I build Go Image with CircleCI, I get runtime/cgo: pthread_create failed: Operation not permitted

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, go, circleci

I was building and pushing Docker Image to ECR with CircleCi, and it was working fine until June, but since July, I started getting the following error.

```
+ docker buildx build -f ././docker/deploy/go/Dockerfile -t ************.dkr.ecr.**************.amazonaws.com/test/dev-apps:207859b16c2d2xxxxxf1bc380e6af51da6 --platform linux/amd64 --progress plain --push .
#1 [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile
#1 sha256:dd7da24342fd3375a5753c5d2c78dc06093c3b8a23395f84219cadf7893cecb3
#1 transferring dockerfile: 214B done
#1 DONE 0.1s

#2 [internal] load .dockerignore
#2 sha256:1c1038364a9bd22a129602e0155e97060a7cc9cf1ea51252adce16810218ace5
#2 transferring context: 2B done
#2 DONE 0.0s

#3 [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/golang:1.19
#3 sha256:e028fb171480e8a4266e2187564aff469d1f24d15b9d9272a382ed147f39f366
#3 DONE 0.3s

#4 [1/5] FROM docker.io/library/golang:1.19@sha256:031338ed4f8477cfa39ac084317f3b5a45d21018279c5597c19a6cb0113e2e18
#4 sha256:6b428566a2416bbb1bf19c17a50102a8a22232467b7069b8daae7b8c2de88fc4
#4 resolve docker.io/library/golang:1.19@sha256:031338ed4f8477cfa39ac084317f3b5a45d21018279c5597c19a6cb0113e2e18 done
#4 ...

#6 [internal] load build context
#6 sha256:dd46861b409a5b5107da854f8d7654c2b7d9721af9612233122502b434e4877e
#6 transferring context: 362.55kB 0.0s done
#6 DONE 0.0s

#4 [1/5] FROM docker.io/library/golang:1.19@sha256:031338ed4f8477cfa39ac084317f3b5a45d21018279c5597c19a6cb0113e2e18
#4 sha256:6b428566a2416bbb1bf19c17a50102a8a22232467b7069b8daae7b8c2de88fc4
#4 sha256:031338ed4f8477cfa39ac084317f3b5a45d21018279c5597c19a6cb0113e2e18 2.36kB / 2.36kB done
#4 sha256:4aa39f9ad563cc9977b9a5abdf8e16c5df86e1b200e4b9a24ed357352a3e2f29 1.58kB / 1.58kB done
#4 sha256:62fbd11f8190742df2f7a20e2d342754413b218443f29192138e2fcc6702d493 6.86kB / 6.86kB done
#4 sha256:d52e4f012db158bb7c0fe215b98af1facaddcbaee530efd69b1bae07d597b711 5.24MB / 49.55MB 0.1s
#4 sha256:7dd206bea61ff3e3b54be1c20b58d8475ddd6f89df176146ddb7a2fd2c747ea2 4.19MB / 24.03MB 0.1s
#4 sha256:2320f9be4a9c605d1ac847cf67cec42b91484a7cf7c94996417a0c7c316deadc 2.10MB / 64.11MB 0.1s
#4 sha256:d52e4f012db158bb7c0fe215b98af1facaddcbaee530efd69b1bae07d597b711 15.73MB / 49.55MB 0.2s
#4 sha256:7dd206bea61ff3e3b54be1c20b58d8475ddd6f89df176146ddb7a2fd2c747ea2 16.78MB / 24.03MB 0.2s
#4 sha256:2320f9be4a9c605d1ac847cf67cec42b91484a7cf7c94996417a0c7c316deadc 14.68MB / 64.11MB 0.2s
#4 sha256:d52e4f012db158bb7c0fe215b98af1facaddcbaee530efd69b1bae07d597b711 36.70MB / 49.55MB 0.4s
#4 sha256:7dd206bea61ff3e3b54be1c20b58d8475ddd6f89df176146ddb7a2fd2c747ea2 24.03MB / 24.03MB 0.3s done
#4 sha256:2320f9be4a9c605d1ac847cf67cec42b91484a7cf7c94996417a0c7c316deadc 34.60MB / 64.11MB 0.4s
#4 sha256:543c0c50a70de44530fb9f35321081e7dd67f9aeae1ca5ab99161eb6322e2868 1.05MB / 92.23MB 0.4s
#4 sha256:d52e4f012db158bb7c0fe215b98af1facaddcbaee530efd69b1bae07d597b711 45.09MB / 49.55MB 0.5s
#4 sha256:2320f9be4a9c605d1ac847cf67cec42b91484a7cf7c94996417a0c7c316deadc 44.04MB / 64.11MB 0.5s
#4 sha256:543c0c50a70de44530fb9f35321081e7dd67f9aeae1ca5ab99161eb6322e2868 12.58MB / 92.23MB 0.5s
#4 sha256:d52e4f012db158bb7c0fe215b98af1facaddcbaee530efd69b1bae07d597b711 49.55MB / 49.55MB 0.6s done
#4 sha256:2320f9be4a9c605d1ac847cf67cec42b91484a7cf7c94996417a0c7c316deadc 54.53MB / 64.11MB 0.6s
#4 sha256:543c0c50a70de44530fb9f35321081e7dd67f9aeae1ca5ab99161eb6322e2868 23.07MB / 92.23MB 0.6s
#4 sha256:f11b4d267f1301a479ae8f56fdd8b7e9244ea7f9f0547d7a04f7b86c907fb982 0B / 149.13MB 0.6s
#4 sha256:2320f9be4a9c605d1ac847cf67cec42b91484a7cf7c94996417a0c7c316deadc 64.11MB / 64.11MB 0.8s done
#4 sha256:543c0c50a70de44530fb9f35321081e7dd67f9aeae1ca5ab99161eb6322e2868 37.53MB / 92.23MB 0.8s
#4 sha256:f11b4d267f1301a479ae8f56fdd8b7e9244ea7f9f0547d7a04f7b86c907fb982 15.73MB / 149.13MB 0.8s
#4 sha256:543c0c50a70de44530fb9f35321081e7dd67f9aeae1ca5ab99161eb6322e2868 47.19MB / 92.23MB 0.9s
#4 sha256:f11b4d267f1301a479ae8f56fdd8b7e9244ea7f9f0547d7a04f7b86c907fb982 27.88MB / 149.13MB 0.9s
#4 extracting sha256:d52e4f012db158bb7c0fe215b98af1facaddcbaee530efd69b1bae07d597b711
#4 sha256:894a6b0c636aaf7d2e33be6a92499835e75e36521ab1429f9aafb3c6427079d0 156B / 156B 0.8s done
#4 sha256:543c0c50a70de44530fb9f35321081e7dd67f9aeae1ca5ab99161eb6322e2868 57.17MB / 92.23MB 1.0s
#4 sha256:f11b4d267f1301a479ae8f56fdd8b7e9244ea7f9f0547d7a04f7b86c907fb982 36.70MB / 149.13MB 1.0s
#4 sha256:543c0c50a70de44530fb9f35321081e7dd67f9aeae1ca5ab99161eb6322e2868 77.59MB / 92.23MB 1.2s
#4 sha256:f11b4d267f1301a479ae8f56fdd8b7e9244ea7f9f0547d7a04f7b86c907fb982 56.62MB / 149.13MB 1.2s
#4 sha256:543c0c50a70de44530fb9f35321081e7dd67f9aeae1ca5ab99161eb6322e2868 89.72MB / 92.23MB 1.3s
#4 sha256:f11b4d267f1301a479ae8f56fdd8b7e9244ea7f9f0547d7a04f7b86c907fb982 66.06MB / 149.13MB 1.3s
#4 sha256:543c0c50a70de44530fb9f35321081e7dd67f9aeae1ca5ab99161eb6322e2868 92.23MB / 92.23MB 1.4s done
#4 sha256:f11b4d267f1301a479ae8f56fdd8b7e9244ea7f9f0547d7a04f7b86c907fb982 77.59MB / 149.13MB 1.4s
#4 sha256:f11b4d267f1301a479ae8f56fdd8b7e9244ea7f9f0547d7a04f7b86c907fb982 87.03MB / 149.13MB 1.5s
#4 sha256:f11b4d267f1301a479ae8f56fdd8b7e9244ea7f9f0547d7a04f7b86c907fb982 96.47MB / 149.13MB 1.6s
#4 sha256:f11b4d267f1301a479ae8f56fdd8b7e9244ea7f9f0547d7a04f7b86c907fb982 106.95MB / 149.13MB 1.7s
#4 sha256:f11b4d267f1301a479ae8f56fdd8b7e9244ea7f9f0547d7a04f7b86c907fb982 116.39MB / 149.13MB 1.8s
#4 sha256:f11b4d267f1301a479ae8f56fdd8b7e9244ea7f9f0547d7a04f7b86c907fb982 136.31MB / 149.13MB 2.0s
#4 sha256:f11b4d267f1301a479ae8f56fdd8b7e9244ea7f9f0547d7a04f7b86c907fb982 145.75MB / 149.13MB 2.1s
#4 sha256:f11b4d267f1301a479ae8f56fdd8b7e9244ea7f9f0547d7a04f7b86c907fb982 149.13MB / 149.13MB 2.2s done
#4 extracting sha256:d52e4f012db158bb7c0fe215b98af1facaddcbaee530efd69b1bae07d597b711 2.0s done
#4 extracting sha256:7dd206bea61ff3e3b54be1c20b58d8475ddd6f89df176146ddb7a2fd2c747ea2 0.1s
#4 extracting sha256:7dd206bea61ff3e3b54be1c20b58d8475ddd6f89df176146ddb7a2fd2c747ea2 0.4s done
#4 extracting sha256:2320f9be4a9c605d1ac847cf67cec42b91484a7cf7c94996417a0c7c316deadc
#4 extracting sha256:2320f9be4a9c605d1ac847cf67cec42b91484a7cf7c94996417a0c7c316deadc 1.8s done
#4 extracting sha256:543c0c50a70de44530fb9f35321081e7dd67f9aeae1ca5ab99161eb6322e2868 0.1s
#4 extracting sha256:543c0c50a70de44530fb9f35321081e7dd67f9aeae1ca5ab99161eb6322e2868 2.1s done
#4 extracting sha256:f11b4d267f1301a479ae8f56fdd8b7e9244ea7f9f0547d7a04f7b86c907fb982
#4 extracting sha256:f11b4d267f1301a479ae8f56fdd8b7e9244ea7f9f0547d7a04f7b86c907fb982 4.2s done
#4 extracting sha256:894a6b0c636aaf7d2e33be6a92499835e75e36521ab1429f9aafb3c6427079d0 done
#4 DONE 12.1s

#5 [2/5] WORKDIR /app
#5 sha256:34d1ef918b6d09f8ba692279dcf9ad72ba13782dc9bbf90381fe1754bc116278
#5 DONE 0.4s

#7 [3/5] COPY ../../. .
#7 sha256:bc500be40bee9eece3ec06d0a07fa79bf6e1b9f2a8d66b1fa20eab7656146297
#7 DONE 0.0s

#8 [4/5] RUN go mod download
#8 sha256:9ee39153ed627919cca760765c1b0c3ab343e8e052767526c702ab7783e2b756
#8 0.283 runtime/cgo: pthread_create failed: Operation not permitted
#8 0.286 SIGABRT: abort
#8 0.286 PC=0x7f7894db6ccc m=0 sigcode=18446744073709551610
#8 0.286 
#8 0.286 goroutine 0 [idle]:
#8 0.286 runtime: g 0: unknown pc 0x7f7894db6ccc
#8 0.286 stack: frame={sp:0x7fff48400090, fp:0x0} stack=[0x7fff47c01510,0x7fff48400520)
#8 0.286 0x00007fff483fff90:  0x0000000000000000  0x0000000000000000 
#8 0.286 0x00007fff483fffa0:  0x0000000000000000  0x0000000000000000 
#8 0.286 0x00007fff483fffb0:  0x0000000000000000  0x0000000000000000 
#8 0.286 0x00007fff483fffc0:  0x0000000000000000  0x0000000000000000 
#8 0.286 0x00007fff483fffd0:  0x0000000000000000  0x0000000000000000 
#8 0.286 0x00007fff483fffe0:  0x0000000000000000  0x0000000000000000 
#8 0.286 0x00007fff483ffff0:  0x0000000000000000  0x0000000000000000 
#8 0.286 0x00007fff48400000:  0x0000000000000000  0x0000000000000000 
#8 0.286 0x00007fff48400010:  0x0000000000000000  0x0000000000000000 
#8 0.286 0x00007fff48400020:  0x0000000000000000  0x0000000000000000 
#8 0.286 0x00007fff48400030:  0x0000000000000000  0x0000000000000000 
#8 0.286 0x00007fff48400040:  0x0000000000000000  0x0000000000000000 
#8 0.286 0x00007fff48400050:  0x0000000000000000  0x0000000000000000 
#8 0.286 0x00007fff48400060:  0x0000000000000000  0x0000000000000000 
#8 0.286 0x00007fff48400070:  0x0000000000000000  0x0000000000000000 
#8 0.286 0x00007fff48400080:  0x0000000000000000  0x00007f7894db6cbe 
#8 0.286 0x00007fff48400090: <0x0000000000000000  0xd069df8712bd1200 
#8 0.286 0x00007fff484000a0:  0x0000000000000006  0x00007f7894d29740 
#8 0.286 0x00007fff484000b0:  0x0000000001cd92e0  0x0000000000000178 
#8 0.286 0x00007fff484000c0:  0x0000000000e3cda0  0x00007f7894d67ef2 
#8 0.286 0x00007fff484000d0:  0x00007f7894effe70  0x00007f7894d52472 
#8 0.286 0x00007fff484000e0:  0x0000000000000020  0x0000000000000000 
#8 0.286 0x00007fff484000f0:  0x0000000000000000  0x0000000000000000 
#8 0.286 0x00007fff48400100:  0x0000000000000000  0x0000000000000000 
#8 0.286 0x00007fff48400110:  0x0000000000000000  0x0000000000000000 
#8 0.286 0x00007fff48400120:  0x0000000000000000  0x0000000000000000 
#8 0.286 0x00007fff48400130:  0x0000000000000000  0x0000000000000000 
#8 0.286 0x00007fff48400140:  0x0000000000000000  0x0000000000000000 
#8 0.286 0x00007fff48400150:  0x0000000000000000  0x0000000000000000 
#8 0.286 0x00007fff48400160:  0x0000000000000000  0x0000000000000000 
#8 0.286 0x00007fff48400170:  0x0000000000000000  0xd069df8712bd1200 
#8 0.286 0x00007fff48400180:  0x00007f7894eff840  0x00007f7894eff840 
#8 0.286 runtime: g 0: unknown pc 0x7f7894db6ccc
#8 0.286 stack: frame={sp:0x7fff48400090, fp:0x0} stack=[0x7fff47c01510,0x7fff48400520)
#8 0.286 0x00007fff483fff90:  0x0000000000000000  0x0000000000000000 
#8 0.286 0x00007fff483fffa0:  0x0000000000000000  0x0000000000000000 
#8 0.286 0x00007fff483fffb0:  0x0000000000000000  0x0000000000000000 
#8 0.286 0x00007fff483fffc0:  0x0000000000000000  0x0000000000000000 
#8 0.286 0x00007fff483fffd0:  0x0000000000000000  0x0000000000000000 
#8 0.286 0x00007fff483fffe0:  0x0000000000000000  0x0000000000000000 
#8 0.286 0x00007fff483ffff0:  0x0000000000000000  0x0000000000000000 
#8 0.286 0x00007fff48400000:  0x0000000000000000  0x0000000000000000 
#8 0.286 0x00007fff48400010:  0x0000000000000000  0x0000000000000000 
#8 0.286 0x00007fff48400020:  0x0000000000000000  0x0000000000000000 
#8 0.286 0x00007fff48400030:  0x0000000000000000  0x0000000000000000 
#8 0.286 0x00007fff48400040:  0x0000000000000000  0x0000000000000000 
#8 0.286 0x00007fff48400050:  0x0000000000000000  0x0000000000000000 
#8 0.286 0x00007fff48400060:  0x0000000000000000  0x0000000000000000 
#8 0.286 0x00007fff48400070:  0x0000000000000000  0x0000000000000000 
#8 0.286 0x00007fff48400080:  0x0000000000000000  0x00007f7894db6cbe 
#8 0.286 0x00007fff48400090: <0x0000000000000000  0xd069df8712bd1200 
#8 0.286 0x00007fff484000a0:  0x0000000000000006  0x00007f7894d29740 
#8 0.286 0x00007fff484000b0:  0x0000000001cd92e0  0x0000000000000178 
#8 0.286 0x00007fff484000c0:  0x0000000000e3cda0  0x00007f7894d67ef2 
#8 0.286 0x00007fff484000d0:  0x00007f7894effe70  0x00007f7894d52472 
#8 0.286 0x00007fff484000e0:  0x0000000000000020  0x0000000000000000 
#8 0.286 0x00007fff484000f0:  0x0000000000000000  0x0000000000000000 
#8 0.286 0x00007fff48400100:  0x0000000000000000  0x0000000000000000 
#8 0.286 0x00007fff48400110:  0x0000000000000000  0x0000000000000000 
#8 0.286 0x00007fff48400120:  0x0000000000000000  0x0000000000000000 
#8 0.286 0x00007fff48400130:  0x0000000000000000  0x0000000000000000 
#8 0.286 0x00007fff48400140:  0x0000000000000000  0x0000000000000000 
#8 0.286 0x00007fff48400150:  0x0000000000000000  0x0000000000000000 
#8 0.286 0x00007fff48400160:  0x0000000000000000  0x0000000000000000 
#8 0.286 0x00007fff48400170:  0x0000000000000000  0xd069df8712bd1200 
#8 0.286 0x00007fff48400180:  0x00007f7894eff840  0x00007f7894eff840 
#8 0.286 
#8 0.286 goroutine 1 [running]:
#8 0.286 runtime.systemstack_switch()
#8 0.286        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:459 fp=0xc000042780 sp=0xc000042778 pc=0x4662e0
#8 0.286 runtime.main()
#8 0.286        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:170 +0x6d fp=0xc0000427e0 sp=0xc000042780 pc=0x439ded
#8 0.286 runtime.goexit()
#8 0.286        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1594 +0x1 fp=0xc0000427e8 sp=0xc0000427e0 pc=0x468501
#8 0.286 
#8 0.286 rax    0x0
#8 0.286 rbx    0x7
#8 0.286 rcx    0x7f7894db6ccc
#8 0.286 rdx    0x6
#8 0.286 rdi    0x7
#8 0.286 rsi    0x7
#8 0.286 rbp    0x7f7894d29740
#8 0.286 rsp    0x7fff48400090
#8 0.286 r8     0x0
#8 0.286 r9     0x73
#8 0.286 r10    0x8
#8 0.286 r11    0x246
#8 0.286 r12    0x6
#8 0.286 r13    0x178
#8 0.286 r14    0xe3cda0
#8 0.286 r15    0x7f786d9b835b
#8 0.286 rip    0x7f7894db6ccc
#8 0.286 rflags 0x246
#8 0.286 cs     0x33
#8 0.286 fs     0x0
#8 0.286 gs     0x0
#8 ERROR: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c go mod download]: exit code: 2
------
 > [4/5] RUN go mod download:
------
error: failed to solve: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = executor failed running [/bin/sh -c go mod download]: exit code: 2

Exited with code exit status 1
```

Looking at the contents, I see that `go mod download` is generating `runtime/cgo: pthread_create failed: Operation not permitted` errors.

Here is the CircleCI configuration file.

```
version: 2.1

orbs:
  aws-ecr: circleci/aws-ecr@8.2.1

jobs:
  dev-ecr-push-go-image:
    executor: aws-ecr/default
    steps:
    - run:
        name: docker version
        command: docker version
    - run:
        name: go version
        command: go version
    - aws-ecr/build-and-push-image:
        registry-id: DEV_AWS_ECR_REGISTRY_ID
        aws-access-key-id: DEV_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
        aws-secret-access-key: DEV_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
        public-registry: false
        push-image: true
        dockerfile: ./docker/deploy/go/Dockerfile
        repo: 'aam-delivery-development/aam-delivery-apps'
        tag: '${CIRCLE_SHA1}'

workflows:
  ci_workflow:
    jobs:
    - dev-ecr-push-go-image:
        filters:
          branches:
            only: dev
```

We have not made any changes to the code from when the deployment was successful in June.

Please let me know if there are any other logs needed.
We will provide them.

DockerFile

```
FROM golang:1.19

WORKDIR /app

COPY ../../. .

RUN go mod download

EXPOSE 8080
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I checked the Go image github and the architecture commit came in mid-June, so this is most likely the problem. github.com/docker-library/golang/commits/… I changed the Dockerfile image to golang:1.19.1 and confirmed that it works fine. Thank you very much.